# Should I passdown useContext variables as props in a strict parent-children relationship components in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-props, mobx

I have several components with a strict parent-children relationship, and some commonly used variables are accessed through useContext, which is applied directly to the MobX-State-Tree store.

I have a question: would it be better in performance if I set useContext in the most parent component and then pass down those variables as props, compared to my current approach of using hooks in different child components to retrieve those store variables?

Comment: performance wise it is better to use the context only at the places where it is used. Having a parent component with all state is actually an anti-pattern called `prop drilling` and should be avoided when possible